# Sorteador de Nomes em VUE.JS

Tags: vue.js

Gostaria de uma ajuda para montar um sorteador de nomes.

Criei um `<input type="text">`, consigo alterar ele com a diretiva v-model, mas não consigo preencher o Array da forma correta.

Gostaria que o delimitador do Array fosse a "**,**" cada vez que fosse colocado uma "," passaria a preencher outro elemento do Array.
Alguma dica ?

Segue o código:

```
    <template>
  <div class="nomes">
 <div>
    <input type="text" class="texto" v-model="texto" >{{ texto }}
  </div>

  <div>
  <button 
  v-on:click="Embaralhar"
  class="btn btn-outline-primary m-1">
  Calcular
      {{ label }}
  </button>
  </div>

<div class="alert alert-primary p-5 m-1" :value="name" >
    <p class="font-weight-bold">Resultado</p>
        <h1 class="">{{ name }}</h1>
    </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data: function(){
   return {
     adicionar: "",
     name: [

     ],
     texto: [
         'texto1',
         'texto2',
         'texto3'
     ]
   }
  },
  name: 'Nome',
  methods:{
  Embaralhar(){
    this.name = this.texto[Math.ceil(Math.random() * (this.texto.length - 1))]
   }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
 .content {
        grid-area: content;
        background-color: #efefef;
        padding: 20px;
    }
.texto{
        height: 100px;
        width: 400px;
    }
input {
    height: 50px;
    width: 60px;
    
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 40px;

    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row-start: row1-start;
}
div.display {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;

    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: third-line / 4;
    
}
button{
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o método `String.prototype.split()` você consegue que, a cada vírgula, seja um elemento em seu array.

Se você digitar: 'João, Maria'
Você terá: `['João', 'Maria']`

```
const nomes = 'João, Maria'
const arrayNomes = nomes.split(',')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split